# wix - no rows with my CA in InstallExecuteSequence Table

Tags: wix, custom-action

i have code like this

```
<Fragment>  
    <CustomAction Id="IsPrivileged" Error="You should be an adminuser" />  
    <InstallExecuteSequence>  
        <Custom Action="IsPrivileged" Before="LaunchConditions">Not AdminUser</Custom>  
    </InstallExecuteSequence>  
    <CustomAction Id="install_myfile" FileKey="id_myfile.exe" ExeCommand="/install" Return="check"/>  
    <InstallExecuteSequence>  
        <Custom Action="install_myfile" Sequence="5750"/>  
    </InstallExecuteSequence>  
</Fragment>
```

But installer ignores this fragment. i looked the msi-database with Orca.exe. and i found that in InstallExecuteSequence Table there are no rows with this custom actions. what is the problem? should i bind my custom actions to dialog's controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CustomActionRef to reference the Fragment into your Product.

Comment: You should be able to just put it inside of your product element.